# After importing a complextype in one xsd from another xsd, is it possible to have selected subelements of the complex type in the second xsd

Tags: xsd

After importing a complextype in one xsd from another xsd, is it possible to have selected subelements of the complex type in the second xsd

What I mean is :

I have first xsd. -> AddressFile.xsd .In AddressFile.xsd, there is a complex type IndividualAddress, with 5 subelemnts. In the next xsd, Individual.xsd , I am referring to the complext type IndividualAddress in AddressFile.xsd. But in Individual.xsd, I just want DoorNO , StreetNum  and State from the complex Type IndividualAddress directly . Is that possible. Is there any restrictions I can use.

AddressFile.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
           targetNamespace="http://abc/DP/Address">
  <xs:complexType name="IndividualAddress">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Address of an individual
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DoorNO" type="xs:String" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="StreetNum" type="xs:String" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="State" type="xs:String" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:String" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Pin" type="xs:String" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Individual.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:address="http://abc/DP/Address" 
           targetNamespace="http://abc/DP/Individual">

  <xs:import namespace="http://abc/DP/Address" 
             schemaLocation="AddressFile.xsd"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Individual">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Address of an individual
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:String" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:int" 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="DoorNO" type=" address:IndividualAddress " 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="StreetNum" type=" address:IndividualAddress " 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="State" type=" address:IndividualAddress " 
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you want XSD-aware tools to know that complex type Individual is derived from complex type IndividualAddress, you can derive the one from the other.  You will need to do so in two steps:  a restriction step to get rid of the unwanted child elements of the base type and then an extension step to add more elements, at the end.  (*Not* at the beginning.)

If you just want to reuse the elements, the creator of the base schema has done the best job they can to hinder you, by making all the children of IndividualAddress local types, which cannot be referred to from elsewhere.  If they wanted to make reuse easy, or even possible, they would (a) make the elements in question top-level elements, and/or possibly (b) use named model groups to package up groups of useful elements to be used together.